# I am making currency converter in Python, but .isdigit() is not working for me

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import urllib2
import json

print "Hello and welcome to Currency Converter v0.1"

pounds = input("amount you wish to exchange: ")
url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=GBP&to=EUR"
if pounds.isdigit():
    print total
else:
    print "Please, use numeric input, we are not able to convert letters into"
    "money. (But that would be awesome!)"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(response.decode('utf8'))
rates = data ['rate']
total = pounds * rates
```

This is my code. When I run this, I got this error:

```
   if pounds.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' (when entering number into input)
```

or using different input:

```
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asedhfafsdg' is not defined (when entering letters in input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `input()` where you *should* be using [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

In Python 2, `input()` is the same thing as `eval(raw_input())`; e.g. the input given by the user is executed as a Python expression. So if you enter text that can be executed as a valid Python integer literal, you'll get an `int` object, but if you enter `asedhfafsdg` then that's seen as a valid Python identifier and you get a `NameError`.

If you switch to using `raw_input()` instead you do have to convert the input to an integer explicitly:

```
pounds = input("amount you wish to exchange: ")
if pounds.isdigit():
    print total
    pounds = int(pounds)
```

You may also want to study this canonical Stack Overflow post about asking for user input: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also if you are expecting **input** as **Integers** only.

```
>>> try:
...     pounds = int(raw_input("amount you wish to exchange: "))
... except ValueError:
...     print "Please, use numeric input...."
... 
amount you wish to exchange: zero
Please, use numeric input....
```

Comment: Well i'm also using Python 2.7 here not 3. "int" type cast cast works on 2.7 also.

Comment: Please see my answer, I had entered "zero" which is a string and it will show error for any string that's why I return a message in except clause. Please help me if its not good to handle it via exception handling?      CTRL-C interrupts for input() also.

Comment: Yes very true. Catching exception by just "except" also catches KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit etc. If possible please edit my answer to be at least correct at some level or should I delete it?

Comment: Well i tried "except ValueError:" but it is not handling for KeyboardInterrupt. I think it handles specifically for value error here.

Comment: So is it okay if we don't handle KeyboardInterrupt here or should we ignore it and only handle ValueError. 
I am sorry if my reply were not that mature enough.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: You seem to be missing the purpose of the `try..except` mechanism. We use `except` to catch errors that we know how to handle. All other errors *should* interrupt our code.

Comment: Yes John i'm focusing more on that now (digging more in exceptions :))

Comment: @TanveerAlam: much better. I cleaned up the comments now. I recommend you read through [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658) as well; what you tried to cover here is handled in great detail there (plus much more).